# Is Power BI, PowerApps, Flow and Dynamics within the scope of this site?

Tags: discussion

> We accept questions about the SharePoint platform. This is defined as the functionality within:
>
> - the SharePoint server range of products (i.e. SharePoint Foundation and Server, Windows SharePoint Services, SharePoint Portal Server)
> - SharePoint Designer
> - InfoPath where it integrates with SharePoint
> - Yammer where it integrates with SharePoint

InfoPath is getting replaced by PowerApps, and the other ones I listed has been there for some time as well. Both integrate with SharePoint to some extent. I wonder if that will change the scope of this site?

Comment: Powerapps, PowerBI, Flow got SP connectors to interact. Dynamics CRM (365) got native Document integration with SP.. Linked functionality questions will be expected..

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, it should be scope of this site.

New model of SharePoint depend a lot of services, i.e Workflow Manager, Office Online Server, PowerApp, PowerBi, Flows etc. Like

Office web apps till SharePoint 2013 replaced by Office Online server in SharePoint 2016. So if we dont allow the questions for Office online server here than its hard for get solution...SharePoint admin responsible for both product.

Another example, with SharePoint 2013 Microsoft introduced the Microsoft Identity manager for User Profile Sync, again Admin are responsible for it for and SharePoint people can answer.

there are more examples.

If we just restrict the forum to strictly SharePoint questions not related service then it will obsolete very soon. that's my opinion.

I would ask other moderators, if there is a way we can do discuss this and make a decision.

Comment: But then, we'll have to rename the site to something like "365admin.stackexchange.com", don't we? :)

Comment: I dont think, because 365 include exchange, Skype for Business, AD and other products...

Comment: Because these technologies are closely related and knit into SharePoint -- I think it's relative -- as @WaqasSarwarMVP said

Comment: I am fine with SharePoint as long as we don't get questions like:"Help I cant print in word since my Doc is hosted in SharePoint"